# '$ git' autocomplete seems to print colour code

Tags: git, auto-completion

When typing `$ git` in my CLI and pressing tab stop for autocompletion, I get the following sugestions, which look like having extra colour highlighting for `bash` text.

```
$ git 
^[[01;31m^[[K                c^[[m^[[Kheckout-index       d^[[m^[[Kescribe             f^[[m^[[Ksck-objects         l^[[m^[[Kog                  notes                        stage
a^[[m^[[Kdd                  c^[[m^[[Kheck-ref-format     d^[[m^[[Kiff                 g^[[m^[[Kc                   l^[[m^[[Ks-files             pull                         stash
a^[[m^[[Km                   c^[[m^[[Kherry               d^[[m^[[Kiff-files           g^[[m^[[Ket-tar-commit-id    l^[[m^[[Ks-remote            push                         status
a^[[m^[[Knnotate             c^[[m^[[Kherry-pick          d^[[m^[[Kiff-index           g^[[m^[[Krep                 l^[[m^[[Ks-tree              rebase                       submodule
a^[[m^[[Kpply                c^[[m^[[Klean                d^[[m^[[Kifftool             h^[[m^[[Kash-object          mergetool                    reflog                       subtree
a^[[m^[[Krchive              c^[[m^[[Klone                d^[[m^[[Kiff-tree            h^[[m^[[Kelp                 m^[[m^[[Kailinfo             remote                       tag
b^[[m^[[Kisect               c^[[m^[[Kolumn               f^[[m^[[Kast-export          h^[[m^[[Kttp-backend         m^[[m^[[Kailsplit            repack                       verify-commit
b^[[m^[[Klame                c^[[m^[[Kommit               f^[[m^[[Kast-import          h^[[m^[[Kttp-fetch           m^[[m^[[Kerge                replace                      whatchanged 
b^[[m^[[Kranch               c^[[m^[[Kommit-tree          f^[[m^[[Ketch                h^[[m^[[Kttp-push            m^[[m^[[Kerge-base           request-pull                 worktree
b^[[m^[[Kundle               c^[[m^[[Konfig               f^[[m^[[Ketch-pack           i^[[m^[[Kmap-send            m^[[m^[[Kerge-file           reset
c^[[m^[[Kat-file             c^[[m^[[Kount-objects        f^[[m^[[Kilter-branch        i^[[m^[[Kndex-pack           m^[[m^[[Kerge-index          revert
c^[[m^[[Kheck-attr           c^[[m^[[Kredential           f^[[m^[[Kmt-merge-msg        i^[[m^[[Knit                 m^[[m^[[Kerge-octopus        rm
c^[[m^[[Kheck-ignore         c^[[m^[[Kredential-cache     f^[[m^[[Kor-each-ref         i^[[m^[[Knit-db              m^[[m^[[Kerge-one-file       shortlog
c^[[m^[[Kheck-mailmap        c^[[m^[[Kredential-store     f^[[m^[[Kormat-patch         i^[[m^[[Knstaweb             mv                           show
c^[[m^[[Kheckout             d^[[m^[[Kaemon               f^[[m^[[Ksck                 i^[[m^[[Knterpret-trailers   name-rev                     show-branch
```

When I try `git commit` for example with autocompletion, I get the following error message; `git commit` typed manually works fine instead…

```
$ git c^[[m^[[Kommit
git: 'commit' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
```

Does anyone know where this behaviour comes from and how to solve the autocompletion?

Comment: Does `git config --global color.ui false` help?

Comment: No. I also logged out and in again to see wether it may depend on a session variable, but it didn't help.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/181890/147790